# How problematic is it to run vapor saturated liquid through a scroll pump?

Tags: vacuum-pumps

I see that scroll pumps often have "Vapor ratings" of something like N Liters of water per hour. I know in rotary-vane pumps, it's a big no-no to run any kind of vapour through them and you need a cold trap. On the other hand, I know you **can** run vapour through a diaphragm pump, but it's generally regarded as a bad idea.

Are these vapour ratings just for whatever doesn't make it into the cold trap, or do they actually allow you to skip out on the need of the cold trap all together?